# Sencha Touch toolbar alignment

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, toolbar

I have a toolbar in Sencha Touch 1.1. It's pretty simple:

```
Techlink.views.requestsListToolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
    id: 'requestsListToolbar',
    title: 'Service Requests',
    //titleCls: 'TopLevelToolbar',
    items: [
            {xtype: 'spacer'},
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                width: 35,
                height: 25,
                cls: 'refreshbtn',
                handler: function () 
                {
                    RequestJobStore.load();
                }   
            }
        ]
});
```

When it renders, the title is a little high:

[image: the title is too damn high]

However if I add a simple titleCls in my css to bring it down:

```
.TopLevelToolbar 
{
    font-size:0.9em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    color:#ffffff;  
    margin-top:0.8em;
}
```

It puts buttons on a different row to the title!

[image: title kicks buttons off the row]

What gives?? How can I add the CSS, and why is it not aligned in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to convert it to Sencha Touch 2, and the problem vanished.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create one panel and add toolbar in the docked items of panel like

```
 var Panel = new Ext.Panel( {
    layout: {
        type: 'fit',
        align: 'top'
    },
    defaults: {
        flex: 1,
        cls: 'card1',
        layout: 'fit'
    },
    dockedItems: {
        dock: 'top',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        ui: 'light',
                   // change your custom css in touch-charts-full.css by searching for x-toolbar-light
        title: 'Service Requests',
        items: [
                    // items to be included in toolbar
                     ]
    },
    items: []
});
```

Comment: That's what I'm already doing. Sorry I should have also given the code for the panel, which has Techlink.views.requestsListToolbar in its dockeditems.

Comment: Did you try to change it in touch-charts-full.css ?

Answer (score 0):

you can encapsulate the title in a div and then add padding-top to that div, this was the solution i used earlier

`title : '<div style="padding-top: 10px;">Service Requests</div>'`

or better you can create a css class like this and use it

```
.panel_title {
   padding-top: 10px;
}

title : '<div class="panel_title">Service Requests</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and the title is right in the middle of the toolbar.

```
var tlb = new Ext.Toolbar({
    id: 'requestsListToolbar',
    title: 'Service Requests',
    items: [
        {xtype: 'spacer'},
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            width: 35,
            height: 25,
            cls: 'refreshbtn'  
        }
    ]
});

new Ext.Panel({
    dockedItems: [tlb],
    fullscreen: true,
});
```

Are you sure you didn't mess with the original toolbar css ?